# Not sure how to add something to existing google sheets script to update sorting when a different script clears a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two scripts currently running on a grocery list, one to auto sort the list, and the other to clear out a row when the checkbox is checked. Both work, but currently when an item is deleted off the list it doesnt count as an event and trigger the sorting script, is there anyway to make this happen?

Clear Script:

```
function clearContentWhenChecked(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Grocery List" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 5 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0, 2, 1, 5).clearContent();
    e.range.setValue("FALSE")
  }
}
```

Sort Script:

```
function sortOnEvent(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 3;
  var tableRange = "C6:f30";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qPL5yNFGdeUsLw-6TT4xKfkM7qg1TT2DIT5mErHdcZY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There are no triggers that fire when a script clears a cell.

Comment: Can you provide `a different script` of `Not sure how to add something to existing google sheets script to update sorting when a different script clears a cell`?

Answer (score 0):

You just add `sort` method at the end of the function that clears the cell:

```
function clearContentWhenChecked(e) {
 var sh = e.range.getSheet();
 var columnToSortBy = 3;
 var tableRange = "C6:f30";
 var range = sh.getRange(tableRange);
  if (sh.getName() == "Grocery List" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 5 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0, 2, 1, 5).clearContent();
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy }
  }
}
```